# SQL query to sum timestamp diff with null handling

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sum, sql-null

I have a (Oracle)DB table with 2 columns t1 and t2 both with datatype timestamp. column t2 is nullable. I need a SQL query to give me something like the below pseudocode.

```
sum ((t2 if t2 !=null else sys.currentTimestamp) - t1)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here. Firstly, how to substitute a default value for a null. That's easy, we have `nvl` and `coalesce`. For example:

```
with demo (t1, t2) as
     ( select timestamp '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
            , timestamp '2020-01-01 01:02:03'
       from   dual
       union all
       select timestamp '2020-01-01 00:00:00', null from dual )
select t1
     , t2
     , nvl(t2, current_timestamp)
from   demo;

T1                     T2                     NVL(T2,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
---------------------- ---------------------- -----------------------------
2020-01-01 00:00:00.00 2020-01-01 01:02:03.00 2020-01-01 01:02:03.000000000
2020-01-01 00:00:00.00                        2020-08-28 11:25:22.989000000
```

The harder part is how to sum `t2 - nvl(t2,current_timestamp)`. The difference between two timestamps is an `interval day to second`, and although you can do arithmetic with intervals (add, subtract, multiply etc), you can't currently `sum` them. (You can add your vote to [this suggestion on the Oracle Database Ideas forum](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/2903) to get the functionality added.)

In the meantime, you can either [write your own](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/avg-and-sum-for-intervals.html) using the Oracle Data Cartridge Interface, or use a workaround such as this one from Stew Stryker:

```
with demo (t1, t2) as
     ( select timestamp '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
            , timestamp '2020-01-01 01:02:03'
       from   dual
       union all
       select timestamp '2020-01-01 00:00:00', null from dual )
select numtodsinterval(  
         sum(  
           ((sysdate + (nvl(t2,systimestamp) -t1)) - sysdate) * 86400  
           + extract(second from (nvl(t2,systimestamp) -t1))
           - trunc(extract(second from (nvl(t2,systimestamp) -t1)))  
         )  
       , 'second'
       ) as duration
from   demo;

DURATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+000000240 12:37:23.646000000
```

Comment: Thanks @William for the detailed answer. I guess in that case I will have the dataTypes as numeric for t1 & t2, that way I can just use the sum function.